# How to pass two different format object in $http.post?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using angular.js and on controller action method I want to pass two parameters, one json object and another integer.
How can I do that?

```
$http.post('/Customization/SaveCustomization/', $scope.ListCollection).success(function (response) {
                    $('#cartID').html(response);
                });
```

here along with ListCollection i want to pass index of interger type also.

my controller action method is like this.

```
public ActionResult AddMealDealCustozmaitionItems(List<cOrderMealDealItems> lstMealItms, int index)
        {

            return PartialView();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question right, but you can create an object and pass it to the $http.post. Something like

```
var data = {
   'data': $scope.ListCollection,
   'index': $scope.index
}
$http.post('/.../', data).sucesss(..)
```

Comment: You should be able to get it as $_POST['data'] and $_POST['index']. Assuming $_POST is the Server side object containing the POST parameters

Comment: I suppose its upto the serverside framework to do the mapping. From what ive done some time ago, frameworks like commons-beanutils can do the mapping between http requests and server side objects. You would have to write some interceptor otherwise to map inputs to your controller action methods.